# How to perform my actions sequentially with some sleep during it? (C++, winapi)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, timer, sleep

Dears, here I have a small program need to do below action/processes sequentially. now I do below in one function, seems not good:)

1. init user interface, clear EDIT box, Listview; init the buttons status and so on;
2. power supply my devices;
3. need 20seconds sleep or timer, because the device need time for startup;
4. connect with device, read some data from it;
5. need 3seconds to wait feedback from device;
6. got reply from device, decode the data and show them on user interface;

...

For now, I just use sleep() in my program, and do the above steps one by one.
Fortunately, know from stackoverflow that my current way is not good, the feedback and user interface update is very slow, and sometimes, the program even freeze, quite stupid.

And some senior guys told me, I should use timer instead of sleep.

So, my question is: 
how to use timer in my current program? (just do it like the MSDN say?)
How can I improve it base on above requirement?
Do I need multithread for it?

Sorry for so many questions:)

Indeed I want to get everything better.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Don't use polling at all (using an arbitrary sleep is the precursor to polling). Your application will be better, if you subscribe to events, and respond to those instead. Use a timer only to implement timeouts.

Comment: And in case there are no events exposed, the next best option is to use a worker thread to poll the device in a loop with a sleep on each loop iteration.  Either way, the device management definitely does not belong in your app's main UI thread.

Comment: @IInspectable,thank you very much for your help. Actually, I cannot understand what you said"Don't use polling at all", what's it mean? Do you mean I shouldn't use too much sleep() in my program? thanks again.

Comment: @Remy, thank you. After review your comment, I google with "worker thread" keywords, unfortunately, failed to find available link about it. Could ou elaborate your mean again? sorry for my junior level. Anyway, thank you. Have a good day.:)

Comment: @NYwalker look at the Win32 API [`CreateThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453.aspx) function. There is a whole section on [Multiple Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684254.aspx) in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if you are using a specific framework so I am going to assume a windows application using the native windows API directly:

Call [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) passing it your window handle (HWND), and the desired timer interval, and NULL for the TimerProc.

Your window procedure will now periodically be posted WM_TIMER message - you can use the ID parameter you passed to SetTimer in the case you have initiated multiple timers - and to eventually `KillTimer` when you no longer need it.

Comment: you are correct. I'm using a windows application based on winapi, sorry for not specify it. Do you mean I should create many timers for different time intervals, meanwhile, specify different events in timers to process? sorry for my english. thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean that you can, if you want, specify many different timers, and tell them apart by id.